# Angular Router navigation

Tags: html, angular, typescript

In my project in the first component I have an input box, and a button.

```
    <div routerLink="questions" (click)="btnClicked(target.value)" class="button">Click Me</div>
```

In the `app.module.ts` I set up the router, and it is working this way, but the problem is that in the `btnClicked()` function I'm checking **if the user input is valid**, and this way, it doesn't matter if the input is valid or not, the program will navigate to the `questions` component, so I'd like to do this routing in the **typescript file**, right after the validation.

Any suggestions? Thank you guys for the answer(s).

Comment: That is not good practice to do this.you can navigate to another route from btnclicked method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `routerLink` from the button element. And add the Router to the component constructor.

**component.ts**

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router) {}

public btnClicked(event: any): void {
  if(this.valid) {   // check the validation here
     this.router.navigate(['/questions']);
  }
}
```

**component.html**

```
 <div (click)="btnClicked(target.value)" class="button">Click Me</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use the `navigateByUrl` inside the button click function.

```
btnClicked(value){

  if(// your condition){
    this.router.navigateByUrl('questions')

  }
}
```

loose the `routerLink` from div

```
<div  (click)="btnClicked(target.value)" class="button">Click Me</div>
```